# Where can I find a Raku core dump file?

Tags: raku, coredump

I ran /home/foo/bar.p6 from /path/to/data and it says "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

I cannot find the core dump file in /var/crash or my home directory or current working directory.

I think it is Raku itself that core-dumped.

Where would raku put the core dump file if my program caused the dump, and where would I find the dump file if Raku itself core-dumped?

Thanks.

Comment: OOC, which version of Rakudo are you using?  On which backend?

Comment: Thank you very much  Elizabeth Mattijsen. raku --version says "This is Rakudo version 2020.07 built on MoarVM version 2020.07 implementing Raku 6.d."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

/var/crash is for system crash dumps. Core dumps are usually saved under /var/lib/systemd/coredump/, if not, then it might help to also tell us your distribution and whether your system uses systemd. Also check /etc/systemd/coredump.conf for custom settings.

Comment: Thank you very much rubystallion. I use Xubuntu 20.04.1; and I have Rakudo version 2020.05.1 built on MoarVM version 2020.05; my /var/lib/systemd/coredump/ is empty. Maybe nothing is actually dumped.

Comment: you can check the file `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` to see where the kernel is configured to put (and what to name) core dump files; if systemd coredumpctl is configured on your system, it would look like `|/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %c %h` where the pipe character at the start indicates it should be piped into a process, in your case it's likely an absolute or relative path. also, `dmesg` may give a little more information about the segfault and coredump